# Accessibility Issue: Background Images Hiding Child Text

Tags: html, css, accessibility, screen-readers

I have the following:

```
<div class="backgroundImage">
    <div>"Hello world!"</div>
</div>
```

On Android browsers, "Hello world!" will not be read by Talkback/screen readers when selected. However, if I remove the "backgroundImage" class and select it, it will be read. Is there a way I can continue using the background image but with the text of its child nodes readable? Thanks.

Edit:

```
.backgroundImage { 
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-image:url('backgroundImage.png');
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to solve this without the css in `backgroundImage` class? (Even  css which might be inherited from parent elements might be causing the problem). Please provide the relevant info or your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: is this the whole code related to the problem? does this have any parent elements which are positioned or having attributes like `z-index`..?

Comment: The rest of my code is not related to this problem; this is the only relevant code. Removing the backgroundImage class from the parent element allows its children to be read by Talkback. Z-index is not being set.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered what was wrong. Looking back, another individual added an opacity=0 style to the elements that I was unaware of; removing this solved the issue.